# expected '=', ';'.. before -> token

Tags: c, pointers

Following parts of my code are not compiling:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}
struct Node head;
head->next = NULL;
```

the error message says:
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or 'attrivute' before '->' token 
  head->next = NUL;

Comment: `head->next` is just a shorcut for `(*head).next`, iff `head` is a pointer. In your case it's not, so `*head` does not make sense.

Comment: You need a semicolon after the closing brace of your struct definition.

Answer (score 1):

As head is structure and not pointer you can access the element with `.`:

```
head.next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

head is not a pointer. Use '.':

```
head.next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is no semi-colon after your struct definition:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} ;   /* <==== here */
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you should use the dot to access members, it seems that you are placing executable code in a declaration section. The `head.next = NULL;` must be inside a function.

Comment: Struct declaration may appear inside function body

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.` instead`->`, and be careful about file scope, your executable code should be inside a function.

Try:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}; //Remember the ;

int main(){
    struct Node head;
    head.next = NULL;

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}; //Remember the ;

struct Node head;

int main(){
    head.next = NULL;

    //...

    return 0;
}
```